# Sony VAIO E Series - SVE15129CGB with ATI 7570 HD: Screen Brightness Adjustment

Tags: screen, brightness, vaio, sony

I have been running Ubuntu for a long time now! But since I installed it on my VAIO I just can't adjust the brightness. The Fn button does not work (although it does work for the volume adjustment), and none of the scripts circulating in the forum have worked so far! Any pointers will be appreciated! Thanks People.

Answer (score 0):

I also had the exactly same problem with my sony vaio. I tried all the solution I could find on the internet. The only solution that worked for me is here. [Brightness Control Keys on Sony Vaio not working on 12.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/236616/brightness-control-keys-on-sony-vaio-not-working-on-12-10)