# Brightness Control Keys on Sony Vaio not working on 12.10

Tags: 12.10, nvidia, brightness, vaio

Hi everyone i'm having a problem that for what i have seen its very common with the latest version of ubuntu.

So I updated my graphics drivers on my laptop to the latest nvidia ones but now my brightness keys do not work anymore. I used <kbd>Fn + F5</kbd> to lower brightness and <kbd>Fn + F6</kbd> to increase it.

I have a Sony Vaio laptop model `VPCCW25FL` and my GPU is an `Nvidia GT330M`. I have been trying some of the solutions answered here but none of them seem to work. I'm really annoyed by this and it's a chore that every so often I have to run a terminal command to lower the brightness but after a while it increases again!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Controlling Brightness in Sony Vaio SVE151A11W |Not Working|](http://askubuntu.com/questions/230929/controlling-brightness-in-sony-vaio-sve151a11w-not-working)

Answer (score 0):

it happened to me

my system info
**ubuntu 14.04** 
**nvidia gt330m**

**HOW I SOLVED IT**

**note:** if you havent installed  nvidia driver. Install it before you continue this.

in terminal

```
# nvidia-xconfig
```

this creates /etc/X11/xorg.conf . edit it.

```
# sudo su  // become root
# gedit /etc/X11/xorg.conf
```

find **Section "device"** in text.
and  add this

```
 Option "RegistryDwords" "EnableBrightnessControl=1"
```

it shold look like it on the rightside

```
from this                        TO   this
```

```
Section "Device"                  | Section "Device"
 Identifier "Device0"             |   Identifier  "Device0"
 Driver     "nvidia"              |   Driver      "nvidia"
 VendorName "NVIDIA Corporation"  |   VendorName  "NVIDIA Corporation"
                                  |   Option "RegistryDwords" "EnableBrightnessControl=1"
EndSection                        | EndSection
```

save changes (ctrl+S). 
log out. log in.

we are done!!
now Fn + Up,Down  is adjusting the brightness.